# smb file copy results in exception

Tags: java, smb

I am trying to copy a jar file to windows share folder and i am using smb to do it but i am getting the following error. Is there any other way to copy the files?

```
    String user = "abc";
    String pass ="xyz";
    try{
        String sharedFolder="tmp/share/sample.jar";
        String path="smb://1.2.3.4/"+sharedFolder;
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
        SmbFile localFile = new SmbFile("C:/abc/exz/sample.jar");
        localFile.copyTo(smbFile);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exception :

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to negotiate
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Timeout trying to open socket
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.start(SmbTransport.java:315)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate0(SmbTransport.java:865)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:941)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:827)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:797)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.copyTo(SmbFile.java:2022)
    at copyToWindows.copyFile(copyToWindows.java:26)
    at copyToWindows.main(copyToWindows.java:14)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:947)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:827)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:797)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.copyTo(SmbFile.java:2022)
    at copyToWindows.copyFile(copyToWindows.java:26)
    at copyToWindows.main(copyToWindows.java:14)
```

I am able to write to a file remotly.

```
String sharedFolder="tmp/share/text.txt";
        String path="smb://1.2.3.4/"+sharedFolder;
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
        SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
    smbfos.write("TEsting ".getBytes());
```

Comment: It's looking like it can't make the network connection. Can you try opening that share from the same computer in a different way, such as with a file browser or `smbclient`?

Comment: I am able to open the connection from the share. ALso i am able to copy a file to the location as well. I have updated the code as well

Comment: I'm not familiar with JCIFS, but are you sure that the target `smbFile` should be a directory?

Comment: Its actually a file. I tried giving file as well but it didnt go throrugh.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using latest jar which is jcifs-1.3.15.jar as of now and not the lower versions like jcifs-1.1.11.jar etc.